# How to populate google maps with form data in jQuery mobile

Tags: php, forms, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I'm looking to have a form in my mobile version of my site that will take either the zip code or city and state plus a radius around that location and display the number of locations of a particular business.

```
<form id="mobileMapper" action="mapresults.php" method="post">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label formContainer">
                <label for="ziCity">City &amp; State, or Zip:</label>
                <input type="text" name="zipCity" id="zipCity" value="" placeholder="ex: Chicago, IL or 60602" />
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <label for="radius">Radius:</label>
                        <select name="radius" id="radius">
                           <option value="5">5 miles</option>
                           <option value="10">10 miles</option>
                           <option value="20">20 miles</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b">Submit</button></div>     
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Google Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).